# Where did Shem's, Ham's and Japeth's wives come from?

Tags: women, genealogy, noach-noah-the-man

I can't find any information regarding the ancestry line of Noah's sons' respective wives. From whom did they descend?

Comment: I would assume they descended from their parents. ;) Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Eldon. I hope you enjoy your stay.

Comment: What were their names again? :)

Comment: The only reference is the Medrash that Noach's wife was Na'amah the daughter of Lemech and the sister of Tuval-Kayin. There is no reference that I know of which family the wives of his sons came from. We only know that they did not have children before the flood. http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8168/jewish/Chapter-4.htm#v=22

Comment: Also, how did they not all die from severe inbreeding? And how did eight million species fit on a boat? And how about the genetic evidence showing that our common ancestor didn't live 5000 years ago?